# How to cancel a rm command?

Tags: rm

There are a lot of questions about how to **undo a finished** `rm` command.
In my case, my rm started asking:
"Are you sure you want to delete this file?"

And I need to confirm for each one of them. Instead of manually confirming "y/n":

1. Can I set "yes" to the remainder while being asked for y/n for the
   n'th file? (equivalent to "Yes to All" tickbox on Windows) (I know
   the `yes | rm` trick before starting)
2. Can I abort the operation while being asked for y/n for the n'th
   file? (except for shutting down the machine :))

Comment: Just hit ctrl-c and start it again? Btw, with -f it shouldn't ask you anything - that's kind of the point of -f.

Comment: You are right, removed "-f" from the title of my question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To accomplish request 1 you will need to use a more sophisticated program than `yes` to send `y` N number of times and then pass keyboard input through beyond that.  You can't do it with `rm` except to always ask (`rm -i`) or to never ask (`rm -f`).

You can always abort `rm` by

- pressing Control-C to interrupt it (sends SIGINT),
- pressing Control-Z to stop it (sends SIGSTOP) and then killing it,
- sending a SIGTERM (`kill`), or
- sending it a SIGKILL (`kill -9`).

This won't undo any file operations `rm` has already performed, but they will prevent it from performing any further file operations.  If the `rm` process is currently prompting for user input it is not actively unlinking any files so killing it will merely prevent it from continuing.

Comment: What about `yes | head -9 | rm...` to get 9 (for example) yes's?

Comment: @JeffSchaller That would get to the 9th y/n without input but you wouldn't be able to answer y/n to the 10th.

Comment: One could use `{ yes | head -n9; yes n; } | rm -i …` to delete first 9 files, then answer, "no" for any remaining files (and of course the `{ … }` part could be expanded to cover any possible combination of numbers).

Comment: ...though I don't see what it could be useful for. If you know which files you want unliked/not unlinked, why not pass the correct arguments to `rm` instead of building twisted, unreliable commands?

Answer (score 10):

GNU rm supports `-i`, which I assume is what you are referring to and
asks for confirmation for each file, but also `-I`, which is a little
different:

```
-I     prompt once before removing  more  than  three  files,  or  when
       removing  recursively.  Less intrusive than -i, while still giv‐
       ing protection against most mistakes
```

As to whether it's possible to stop an interaction with rm after it
has started, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> should do it.

Answer (score 2):

with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> you will be able to cancel the operation.

But if you look in your `.bashrc` file, you can comment the alias that force the confirmation, it use the `-i` param as expained dhag.

in you `.bashrc` you will find a entry like this :

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

if you comment it, your `rm -f` will works directly

Answer (score 1):

Under `bash`, you can bypass an alias by prepending a `\` to the command, so

```
rm filename
```

becomes

```
\rm filename
```

Comment: I don't see how this has something to do with my question of "how to interrupt the rm process"

Comment: @AndreyDoronin It addresses your usage of approaches such as *I know the `yes | rm` trick before starting*

Comment: @AndreyDoronin> it tells how not to end up having to ask *how to interrupt the rm process* for the reasons you gave in your question.